# GAE JAVA Code changes not reflecting in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am asking this question after looking for an answer to my problem from past two days.

**THINGS ALREADY TRIED**

I have tried following things in eclipse:

1. Clean/Build my Project
2. Renaming my JavaScript file (changes in this file are the one which not reflecting)
3. Terminating all Launches from Console (using double cross icon)
4. Terminate/Disconnect all Launches from Debug window (Right click on launch and selecting the option Terminate/Disconnect all)
5. Removing all the files from the project, clean the project and copied again the files.
6. Clearing browser cache/history from browser's options (Used Google Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600)
7. Used this code

`$("#form-contact-form").on('click', '#btn-contact-from-submit', function () {
    //my code goes here...
});`

instead of

`$('#btn-contact-from-submit').click(function(){
    //my code goes here...
});`

8. Used `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-contact.js?123"></script>` also

**MY PROBLEM**

I am making a small change, that is adding an event listener to a button element in my html file. I have added an `alert('Sending Message');` too in the listener so that it triggers the alert as soon as it enters the listener code. Previously it was working. But from past two days, whatever changes I do are not reflecting.

**ECLISPE AND GAE PLUGIN VERSION**

1. ECLIPSE: Juno Release build id: 20120614-1722
2. GAE PLUGIN FOR ECLIPSE: 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r42

**CODE**

1. HTML BUTTON ELEMENT

```html
<form action="contact" method="post" id="form-contact-form">
  <div class="col-md-100 fadeInBottom"><button type="submit" id="btn-contact-from-submit">Let it go!</button></div>
</form>
```

2. JAVASCRIPT LISTENER

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn-contact-from-submit').click(function() {
    alert('sending message first');
    var isFormValidated = false;
    isFormValidated = true; //making condition true
    if (isFormValidated) {
      alert('sending message');
      $("#btn-contact-from-submit").html('Wait! It is going!');
      $("#btn-contact-from-submit").prop('disabled', false);

      $("#form-contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
          url: formURL,
          type: "POST",
          data: postData,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //data: return data from server
            $("#btn-contact-from-submit").html('It went! Thank you!');
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //if fails
            alert('Crashed!');
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
      });

      $("#form-contact-form").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
    }
  });

});
```

I am including the JavaScript file just before the body is ending

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-contact.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please help me in this?

If I missed to include any information, please inform me and I will update my question.

Thank You Community!

Comment: Are you seeing the alert message

Comment: use  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-contact.js?233"></script> instead

Comment: @HarbeerKadian No, I am not able to see any of the alert messages.

Comment: @PawanPandey I also tried that. I renamed the whole js file and cclean build the project again, but still its not working.

Comment: can you check if file loads or not. Have you checked the correct file path to js? or you should check it with other browsers too.

Comment: you can check it in firebug for mozilla

Comment: @PawanPandey Thanks Pawan. I checked that in Chrome Console and IE too, the file is getting loaded and no 404 errors are there. Unfortunately I can not use Firefox as it needs to be installed on my system. But I am working on my company system so I don't have admin rights.

Comment: I think it should not but does my company's proxy have any issues on this. This is running on localhost.

Comment: have you tried your js code on the same html file see this fiddle its working there  https://jsfiddle.net/pawanFiddle/pke499wz/

Comment: @PawanPandey Thanks Pawan. When I download the project contents and open the html file normally in a browser, the script is working fine. That is showing both the alerts. I think there is some issue with some kind of cache or something. There is no error in code as far as I think.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out?